# Not able to initialize FormGroup

Tags: angular

I am working on dynamic form and everything seems to be working except exception -

> "**formGroup expects a FormGroup instance**".

I am getting JSONArray(Dynamic Form Array) which after assigning to a variable, I am traversing name of each element to initialize form group inside `ngOnInit` but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

import { UserDataService } from '../../../app-user-services/user- data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-form',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-form.component.css']
})
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit {

  templateId = {
    "data": {
      "id": "Angular4"
    }
  }

  config: any[] = [];

  form: FormGroup;
  @Output() submitted: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder, 
    private userService: UserDataService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getTemplateData(this.templateId).subscribe(result => {
      this.config = result;
      this.form = this.createGroup();
    });
  }

  createGroup() {
    const group = this.fb.group({});
    this.config.forEach(
      control => group.addControl(control.name, this.fb.control(''))
    );
    return group;
  }

}
```

** Here: config value is as following -**

```
config = [{
    "type": "input",
    "label": "Full name",
    "name": "name",
    "placeholder": "Enter your name"
  },
  {
    "type": "select",
    "label": "Favourite food",
    "name": "food",
    "options": ["Pizza", "Hot Dogs", "Knakworstje", "Coffee"],
    "placeholder": "Select an option"
  },
  {
    "label": "Submit",
    "name": "submit",
    "type": "button"
  },
];
```

**Result** :

> DynamicFormComponent.html:4 ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

Example:

```
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <input formControlName="firstName">
</div>
```

In your class:

```
this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
   firstName: new FormControl()
});
```

**This Exception comes when:-**

```
this.config = result;
```

So basically after I assign JsonArray to config, this exception seems to come.

If FormGroup gets initialized my code would work perfectly.

Comment: What's your problem

Comment: I don't understand your example. Where do you use that html code? What is connection between `this.myGroup` and `DynamicFormComponent`?

Comment: My FormGroup is not getting initiliazed .

Comment: @friddo - ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

       Example:

       
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });

.. This is exception in console

Comment: Try to console.log( this.createGroup()) before assigning it to  this.form = this.createGroup();
I believe you are not able to create formgroup instance and passsing null or undefined.
Can you please confirm, is that same ?

Comment: @ Narendra Singh Rathore - Console.log(group) is printing data but not returning it . Inside  createGroup() , if i console.log(group) , it prints data but i think its not returning group data when it gets called ngOnInit()